# jquery - how to convert url based pdf file to base64 and download it

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, base64

I want to digitally sign my pdf but it needs base64 file to signature the file ...  i want to create a function where i will only provide the pdf url and it will convert into base64 pdf .. and then i want to download the base 64 converted file

```
<script>
    var url = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tutorial.pdf";
        function convert(url){
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "get",
                success: function(res){
                    var file = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(res)));
                    var nfile = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + decodeURIComponent(escape(file));
                    var dlnk = document.getElementById('download');
                    dlnk.href = nfile;
                    dlnk.click();
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

This code is working but when i open the downloaded PDF it shows blank PDF. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
download('https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tutorial.pdf','html_tutorial');

function download(url, fileName) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = (event.loaded / event.total)*100;
            //yourShowProgressFunction(percentComplete);
        } 
    };

    xhr.onload = function(event) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            _saveBlob(this.response, fileName);
        }
        else {
            //yourErrorFunction()
        }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function(event){
        //yourErrorFunction()
    };

    xhr.send();
}
function _saveBlob(response, fileName) {
    if(navigator.msSaveBlob){
        //OK for IE10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(response, fileName);
    }
    else{
        _html5Saver(response, fileName);
    }
}

function _html5Saver(blob , fileName) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

[Copied from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332232/7035903)

Comment: but i want base64 string to digitally sign the document